# Symfony2: set a class to the select generated by birthdate widget

Tags: css, forms, symfony

In my form I generate the birthdate field with:

```
{{form_widget(form.birthdate) }}
```

The following html is generated:

```
<div id="fos_user_registration_form_birthdate">
    <select id="fos_user_registration_form_birthdate_month"     name="fos_user_registration_form[birthdate][month]">
    <select id="fos_user_registration_form_birthdate_day" name="fos_user_registration_form[birthdate][day]">
    ,
    <select id="fos_user_registration_form_birthdate_year" name="fos_user_registration_form[birthdate][year]">
</div>
```

I want to add a class to the select in order to customize their style.
How can I do that?

PS: If I add

```
'attr' => array('class' => 'select-style'),
```

the class is attributed to `<div id="fos_user_registration_form_birthdate">`, not to the select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the best you can do without overriding the twig template for the date widget yourself. If you look at the default template for the date widget [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L127) you'll see there are no attributes passed specifically to the select inputs. You can, however, apply a class to the containing div and then use a CSS selector like this to style them

```
.dateWrapper select { /* style here */ }
```

Answer (score 9):

```
{{ form_widget(account_form.birthday.day,{'attr':{'class':'some_class'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(account_form.birthday.month,{'attr':{'class':'some_class'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(account_form.birthday.year,{'attr':{'class':'some_class'}}) }}
```